# Javascript problem in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, firefox

I know it's a long shot with so little details I can provide, but here's the problem:

I have an asp.net (3.5) application, which I'm trying to run on IE,Firefox and Chrome.
On IE and Chrome EVERYTHING works just fine, but ***Firefox*** causes trouble:

On Firefox, when clicking SOME of the link buttons I have,the status bar shows the relevant `javascript:__doPostBack('...',")` call, but nothing happens (no post back or anything..the button simply doesn't respond).

An example `<asp:LinkButton>`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="bAccountID" onClick="ViewAccountDetails" runat="server"
    CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Users_aID") %>'> 
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "iAccountID") %> 
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Important to say:

1. Some of the links ***do*** work on Firefox, and as far as I can see all `.aspx` pages the buttons point to were designed the same.
2. Again, on IE and Chrome - NO PROBLEM!
3. Javascript in Firefox is ***enabled***.
4. tried to run debug and put a break point in a relevant eventhandler for one of the clicks - simply doesn't go there.
5. An example for a standard non-working linkbutton:

Any smart and well explained idea will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can't get the code to show up properly - anyone with better markdown-fu around?

Comment: Since we cannot see your code we cannot help you.

Comment: Probably a html markup related problem, where ie is behaved diffrently to the wrong markup.
Hard to solve without seeing the html.
I don't find firebug that usefull for finding errors like this, html validation tools or manually looking at the html (it ifs a small page) are better

Comment: Can you add to your post, the rendered HTML markup of the button?

Comment: the problem with the markdown is putting code following a numbered list. for some reason it sends markdown AWOL :)

Comment: AndreasN - html problem where? In the .aspx calling or in the .aspx called??

Comment: @question-author, you posted the ASPX markup, how about the rendered HTML markup in firefox?

Answer (score 5):

The best place to start would be to get the "Firebug" plugin for Firefox.

What will probably happen when you click the problem links is that a JavaScript error will appear in Firebug and show you exactly where the problem lies.

It's a free download, which you can find by clicking on Tools > Add-Ons in the Firefox menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Internet Explorer and see if the same thing occurs, if not then use FireBug as [@Sohnee says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554861/javascript-problem-in-firefox/1554873#1554873).

Comment: Dude, I specifically said that on IE everything works perfectly fine..10x

Comment: Give the guy a break, probably overworked, neutralise your comment :P

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem like this in the past specifically with firefox and found that re-registering the framework with iis via aspnet_regiis.exe -i can sometimes fix the problem.